# What does "to have a connection with someone" means in the context of dating?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I had an argument with someone about the meaning of that expression. We were discussing whether this means "to have an emotional attachment to someone" or if it means "to contact someone" (like texting or speaking to someone you went on a date). How should that expression be interpreted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a connection to someone:

It means you feel something for the person.

It is intuitive, not based on reality, mostly fantasy because after all can one really tell if one is compatible with someone with just one date?

It has no precise meaning. In fact, it's just small-talk BS or an indirect way of saying  you are attracted to the person. [caveat: my opinion]

Comment: In Victorian times, to "have connection" (no article) with someone meant something else.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Victorian times are not relevant here.

Comment: Victorians are always relevant to me.